# Способ добавить в json файл запись с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется `data.json` с такими данными:

```
[
    {"name":"checkbox_0","state":"false"},
    {"name":"checkbox_3","state":"true"},
    {"name":"checkbox_2","state":"true"}
]
```

Получаю данные с помощью `$.getJSON();`

1. Как мне добавить cтроку вида: `{"name":"checkbox_5","state":"true"}` ?
2. Как записать эти изменения обратно в `data.json`?

Comment: А не проще ли отправить новые данные на сервер и там дописать их в файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PUSH](http://javascript.ru/array/push)

```
var data = [
             {"name":"checkbox_0","state":"false"},
             {"name":"checkbox_3","state":"true"},
             {"name":"checkbox_2","state":"true"}
           ];
data.push({"name":"checkbox_5","state":"true"});
```

Comment: А как эту обновленную структуру обратно записать в data.json?

Comment: data.json лежит на сервере? Нужен серверный метод, который обработает POST-запрос и перезапишет файл.

Comment: Да, то есть js уже не по силу, только серверным языком это возможно сделать?